# jQuery get request in ASP.Net MVC 5

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I am  using ASP.Net MVC 5. I have a table which contain Roles Table values.
When I click on edit button than it send jQuery request to get data and it return data like `"UMS.Entities.Role"` and I am not getting values from it however I am getting rite response from database but I am getting problem in jQuery.

```
function dataForEdit(id) {
  var data = GetRequestedData('/Admin/Role/Edit/' + id);
  $("#create-form").slideDown();
  $('.formEditBtn').slideDown();
  setInputValue('#role-name', data.Name);
  $("#roleID").attr("value", data.RoleId);        
}
```

`GetRequestedData('/Admin/Role/Edit/' + id)` is separate function which is separate file.

```
function GetRequestedData(url) { 
  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    async: false,
    type: 'GET',
    success: function (data) {
      resultData = data; // here I am getting this UMS.Entities.Role
    },
    error: function (error) {
      $(this).remove();
      alert(error.statusText);
    }
  });

    return resultData
}
```

My controller function is

```
public Role Edit(int id) {
  Role role = _roleService.GetById(id);
  return role;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should return Json result, Can you try this?

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    Role role = _roleService.GetById(id);
    return Json(role , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you're using `async: false` which is very bad practice. Use the async pattern properly and use callbacks to execute logic after the AJAX call completes.

That said, the main issue in your code is because the `Role` class is being serialised via `ToString()`. It would be more applicable to serialise it to JSON instead, something like this:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    Role role = _roleService.GetById(id);
    return Json(role, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Then in your JS code you can retrieve the properties from the `Role` class in the `data` argument provided to the `success` callback:

```js
function dataForEdit(id) {
  GetRequestedData('/Admin/Role/Edit/' + id, function(data) {
    $("#create-form, .formEditBtn').slideDown();
    setInputValue('#role-name', data.Name);
    $("#roleID").val(data.RoleId);
  });
}

function GetRequestedData(url, callback) {
  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'GET',
    success: callback,
    error: function(error) {
      $(this).remove();
      alert(error.statusText);
    }
  });
}

GetRequestedData('/Admin/Role/Edit/' + id);
```

Comment: Thanks Sir for your sharing your valuable experience it help me alot.

Comment: @KhizranAhmad any reason you felt the need to change the accepted answer?